# creating new email address for every project

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I have to create new email address for every project.I am developing project management app in this application if application user is created new project then for this project my controller should create one email id for that project.so that user can use this for project communication. If again new project is created then controller should able to create new email id.
I have created one class processemail which is processing all emails.For this class i have created manually email id by using following setting.

```
Develop->email Service->new email service --> after this i provided details like which call i am using and all.
```

So i don't want to create email id manually so how i can solve this problem.This is possible in sales forces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to create an email service using Apex. I don't think if that is possible in salesforce as of now. 
But according to me, if you change your flow little bit then you can achieve what you want.

1. When creating a project, ask user to enter email id which is going to be associated with project.
2. Make this field mandatory and in help-text ask user to get it from system admin (system admin will create a new email service and will give email id to user)

This is just a pure suggestion.